# Error when show data from mySQL to View in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I use Laravel to show data from Mysql to View by multi-queries.

Here is my Route:

```
Route::get('/procinstdetail','ProcDetailController@index');
```

And here is my controller:

```
use App\act_hi_taskinst;
use View;

class ProcDetailController extends Controller
{
    private $act_hi_taskinst;

    public function __construct(act_hi_taskinst $act_hi_taskinst) {
        $this -> act_hi_taskinst = $act_hi_taskinst;
    }

    public function index(act_hi_taskinst $act_hi_taskinst, Request $request) 
    {
        $procinstid = $request->get('id');

        return View::make('datatrackingdetail')->with('data', $this->act_hi_taskinst->getData($procinstid));
    }
}
```

And my model:

```
class act_hi_taskinst extends Model
{

    public function getData($procinstid) {
        $data = array();

        $data['taskData'] = DB::select("SELECT NAME_, PRIORITY_, ASSIGNEE_, DUE_DATE_, START_TIME_, END_TIME_, PROC_DEF_ID_ FROM act_hi_taskinst WHERE PROC_INST_ID_ = $procinstid");

        $data['varData'] = DB::select("SELECT NAME_, TEXT_ FROM act_hi_varinst WHERE PROC_INST_ID_ = $procinstid");

        $data['subprocessData'] = DB::select("SELECT * FROM act_hi_procinst WHERE SUPER_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_ = $procinstid");

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Final is fetch data to view:

```
<body>      
        <h2>Task</h2>
        <table border="1" cellspacing = "0" cellpadding = "3">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Priority</th>
                <th>Assignee</th>
                <th>Due Date</th>
                <th>Created</th>
                <th>Completed</th>
            </tr>

            @if(isset($data))
            @foreach($data as $processTaskDataValue)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $processTaskDataValue -> NAME_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $processTaskDataValue -> PRIORITY_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $processTaskDataValue -> ASSIGNEE_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $processTaskDataValue -> DUE_DATE_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $processTaskDataValue -> START_TIME_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $processTaskDataValue -> END_TIME_ }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            @endif
        </table>

        <h2>Variable</h2>
        <table border="1" cellspacing = "0" cellpadding = "3">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>

            @if(isset($data))
            @foreach($data as $processVarDataValue)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $processVarDataValue -> NAME_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $processVarDataValue -> TEXT_ }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            @endif
        </table>

        <h2>Sub Process</h2>
        <table border="1" cellspacing = "0" cellpadding = "3">
            <tr>
                <th>ID_</th>
                <th>PROC_INST_ID_</th>
                <th>BUSINESS_KEY_</th>
                <th>PROC_DEF_ID_</th>
                <th>START_TIME_</th>
                <th>END_TIME_</th>
                <th>DURATION_</th>
                <th>START_USER_ID_</th>
                <th>START_ACT_ID_</th>
                <th>END_ACT_ID_</th>
                <th>SUPER_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_</th>
                <th>DELETE_REASON_</th>
                <th>TENANT_ID_</th>
                <th>NAME_</th>
            </tr>

            @if(isset($data))
            @foreach($data as $subprocessDataValue)
            <tr>
                <td><a href= "{{ url('/procinstdetail') }}?id={{ $subprocessDataValue -> ID_ }}&endtime={{ $subprocessDataValue -> END_TIME_ }}"> {{$subprocessDataValue -> ID_ }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue -> PROC_INST_ID_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue -> BUSINESS_KEY_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue -> PROC_DEF_ID_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue -> START_TIME_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue -> END_TIME_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue -> DURATION_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue -> START_USER_ID_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue -> START_ACT_ID_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue -> END_ACT_ID_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue -> SUPER_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue -> DELETE_REASON_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue -> TENANT_ID_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue -> NAME_ }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            @endif
        </table>
    </body>
```

But I receive error:

> Trying to get property 'NAME_' of non-object.

What's wrong with my code?
I'm new with Laravel so I really don't know how to fix it.

Comment: just remove the space between $subprocessDataValue -> DURATION_ this

Comment: I fixed like @sunilwananje said and it's work. Btw thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Model you are creating array with key taskData, varData and subprocessData and you forgot to use this key to your $data array while getting data

```
    <body>      
        <h2>Task</h2>
        <table border="1" cellspacing = "0" cellpadding = "3">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Priority</th>
                <th>Assignee</th>
                <th>Due Date</th>
                <th>Created</th>
                <th>Completed</th>
            </tr>

            @if(isset($data))
            @foreach($data['taskData'] as $processTaskDataValue)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $processTaskDataValue->NAME_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $processTaskDataValue->PRIORITY_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $processTaskDataValue->ASSIGNEE_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $processTaskDataValue->DUE_DATE_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $processTaskDataValue->START_TIME_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $processTaskDataValue->END_TIME_ }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            @endif
        </table>

        <h2>Variable</h2>
        <table border="1" cellspacing = "0" cellpadding = "3">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>

            @if(isset($data))
            @foreach($data['varData'] as $processVarDataValue)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $processVarDataValue->NAME_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $processVarDataValue->TEXT_ }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            @endif
        </table>

        <h2>Sub Process</h2>
        <table border="1" cellspacing = "0" cellpadding = "3">
            <tr>
                <th>ID_</th>
                <th>PROC_INST_ID_</th>
                <th>BUSINESS_KEY_</th>
                <th>PROC_DEF_ID_</th>
                <th>START_TIME_</th>
                <th>END_TIME_</th>
                <th>DURATION_</th>
                <th>START_USER_ID_</th>
                <th>START_ACT_ID_</th>
                <th>END_ACT_ID_</th>
                <th>SUPER_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_</th>
                <th>DELETE_REASON_</th>
                <th>TENANT_ID_</th>
                <th>NAME_</th>
            </tr>

            @if(isset($data))
            @foreach($data['subprocessData'] as $subprocessDataValue)
            <tr>
                <td><a href= "{{ url('/procinstdetail') }}?id={{ 
                $subprocessDataValue -> ID_ }}&endtime={{ $subprocessDataValue -> 
                 END_TIME_ }}"> {{$subprocessDataValue -> ID_ }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue->PROC_INST_ID_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue->BUSINESS_KEY_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue->PROC_DEF_ID_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue->START_TIME_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue->END_TIME_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue->DURATION_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue->START_USER_ID_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue->START_ACT_ID_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue->END_ACT_ID_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue->SUPER_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue->DELETE_REASON_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue->TENANT_ID_ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subprocessDataValue->NAME_ }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            @endif
          </table>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`DB::select()` will return an Array. So call it's property accordingly.

#### small POC

[image: DB::select()]

**Update:** Also as per other answer, you are not iterating over elements of `$data`, not actual data that you get from `DB::select`.

Comment: yeah my bad! Thanks for your reply!

Comment: you're welcome :) if your problem is solved, you can mark answer as solved.